# Version error, wine is not supported, with Fortnite

Tags: wine, 22.04, lutris

Ive recently started getting into gaming in Ubuntu and I want to install fortnite but there is a weird error: "Version error, wine is not supported" I downloaded Epic Games launcher through lutris, and from epic games launcher I downloaded fortnite, now when I'm trying to launch fortnite it just says the error.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/wine_gaming/comments/wf12o8/fortnite_problem_with_wine/ wine is not supported by Epic Games for running Fortnite (on purpose). You will not be able to play Fortnite on Linux. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at [areweanticheatyet.com](https://areweanticheatyet.com), you'll see that Fortnite has the "denied" tag. This means that the developers of Fortnite, Epic Games, have specifically said that they do not/will not support Linux. The message you see is telling you just that: "wine is not supported" by Epic Games for use running Fortnite. You will unfortunately not be able to play Fortnite on Linux.

Credit to [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/wine_gaming/comments/wf12o8/fortnite_problem_with_wine/) for this information.

Answer (score 0):

Fortnite doesn't work under [Linux](https://lutris.net/games/fortnite/). It thanks to Epic Games that put all effort to break that game, so it doesn't under Linux. The only solution can be either installing Windows to VMs (you can use QEMU/KVM), or forget about that game at all.

Only thing you can try to make it work dirrectly in Linux is:

1. Quit the Epic Games Launcher and make sure no Wine processes are running.
2. Open regedit (right-click Fortnite > Wine registry) and navigate to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Epic Games\Unreal Engine\Identifiers
3. Delete the MachineId key
4. Launch Fortnite

but it may not work too.

Comment: Ill try and see